# Why do i need a mac os to do develop IOS Apps in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter. Why Do I need a Mac OS to develop IOS Applications in Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

Because of Apple policies.

On the page below it is stated that you need to use Xcode 12 to build your iOS Apps, which is only available on Apple computers.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/submitting/

Also as far as I am aware, you need to own an Apple computer / connected account to publish apps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because of Apple policies.

However, you can use tools like Odevio (https://github.com/Odevio/Odevio-CLI). It's a tool that lets you access remote MacOS build machines.

To install Odevio, visit https://www.odevio.com, then setup your Apple developer account with Odevio (https://odevio-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/6_configure_app_store_connect.html) once this is done you can start building your app within the build menu.